# Start GWT+Jetty app with Spring

Tags: spring, maven, gwt

I have an application implemented in GWT using Maven. Currently, the pom.xml stablishes that the application is launch on Jetty and the class that uses that contains the main method.

However, now I need that other application that uses Spring (and Maven) start the GWT application so it starts to listen in the right port. But I do not know how to make this integration.

Do you know how to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Normally both the spring app and the GWT app are web apps, right? so probably both pom.xml are configured to deliver a .war artefact. The traditional way then is to start any servlet container (jetty, tomcat, etc) and drop both .war files on the webapps folder, and any app will be running in a different context.

A less normal scenario, is when the delivered .war of one application includes a servlet container so as it can be run with `java -jar my_app.war`. In this case you have to make one of the apps depend on the other one, and make maven unpack all the stuff to make a bundle with both, normally using the `maven-dependency-plugin` and its `unpack-dependencies` task.

And a third scenario is when your GWT app does not have any server side code, so you could take all the static stuff left by the gwt-compiler in the target folder and simply copy it to the spring app to the src/webapp folder.